# Usage of "I do"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I saw someone replying to a comment in this way on his Photo on Facebook:

```
Comment: Seems, in a good mood.
Reply(of that person): Seems, I do.
```

Does "I do" commensurate with "I am in good mood"
Inferring from above comment, I wrote following sentences. Please guide me, Is this usage correct?

> "I wanted to become a pilot, I still do"

.

> "I had a passion for fishing. I still do"

.

> Person 1 : Do you have a pen?
>
> Person : Yes, I do.

Please explain its usage in a more better way if possible.

Comment: We can't tell what the Comment refers to. Normally, one would say: It seems so/ in relation to some antecedent in the text. What comes before the comment? In any case: /Seems, in a good day/ is very poor English. Sorry. If I say: It seems like you study hard. Another person might say: It seems I do. In English, you can't have a verb like that without a subject.

Comment: Oh Sorry, it was "Seems, in a good mood" I wrote day instead of mood unintentionally.

Comment: I repeat: what is the antecedent? The word seems is just hanging there. There is no way we can KNOW because it does not relate to anything.

Comment: Seeing the photo(in which he was smiling) he commented "Seems, in a good mood".

Comment: Frankly, it doesn't sounds like the person who typed "seems" twice is a fluent English speaker.

Comment: Okay, so one person is seeing a picture of another and comments: "He seems to be in a good mood". Which can be shortened to: [he] Seems [to be] in a good mood. And ***not***: Seems, in a good mood. The answer: "Seems, I do" is meaningless. It would have to be: [it] seems he is [in a good mood].

Comment: They(both) weren't English speakers, actually they were high school English teachers so I had no choice but believing them(to be correct)

Comment: As a native speaker, the entire exchange is not correct.  Sometimes when we are the subject sharing a photo of our own experience, we might omit the subject of the sentence, such as "Baked a cake!" or "Climbed a mountain!" but we wouldn't ever use `Seems` before such a sentence fragment.  And `I do` can't be used to apply to a mood, because being in a mood isn't something you do, it's something you are.   `Seems you're in a good mood!` and `Seems I am!` would make sense.